# What would be the regex pattern to match a String that has a given text and is followed by a 3 digit number with and without hyphen or space?

Tags: java, regex

I have been having lot of issues with regex lately.I would need to check if a particular String is

- Ending by Hello World and then followed  by a 3 digit number i.e **Hello World 123**
- Ending by Hello World and then Followed by a 3 digit number with Hyphen i.e *Hello World-*
- Ending by Hello World and then Followed by a 3 digit number with Hyphen and space in between i.e **Hello World -**
- Ending by Hello World and then Followed by a 3 digit number with a blank space i.e **Hello World+" "**

I am using Java. The text **Hello World** is fixed,the 3 digits are not fixed and can be any number between 0-9

I tried ^.*(\d{3}|-)$" that would match the 3 digit with hyphen/space,unsure how i can combine with **Hello World**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will show an example using Javascript instead of Java because it can be embedded in the page, but the regex should be very similar if not identical.

In order to combine a fixed and a non-fixed, you simply place them together like so:

```
/Hello World\s?(\d{3})$/
```

you will note that I have skipped the `^.*` that you had. This is because we don't care what is at the beginning, so we can simply skip it.

you might also see `\s?` which could be `\s\?` in some regex languages. This says that there is an optional (`?`) whitespace character (`\s`)

the example above just finishes the first example, but I think you can see how to build the others from that start.

```js
function run(){
  try {
    out.value = (new RegExp(regex.value)).test(input.value) ?
    'valid' : 'invalid';
    error.childNodes[0].nodeValue = '';
   } catch(e){
     out.value = 'Invalid regex: ';
         error.childNodes[0].nodeValue = e;
   }
}
input.oninput = run;
regex.oninput = run;
run();
```

```css
#regex, #input {
  width: calc(100% - 7em);
  height: 1.5em;
  padding: .5em;

 }
 
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
 
 #out {
 margin-top: 1em;
 }
```

```html
<div><label>Regex: </label> 
<input  id="regex" value="Hello World( )|( - )(\d{3})"/>

</div>

<div><label>Input: </label>
<input id="input" value="Hello World 123"/>
</div>


<label>Result: </label>
<input id="out" />

<div id="error"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks,I did something like this for Java.
:^.*Hello World \\d{3} ?-?$

Looks allright for now,will test it out with different combinations.Very nice answer !+1